# How to set interval starting at y = 0?

Tags: c#, winforms, axis, mschart

how can I set interval of axisY starting at y = 0? Now,
[I have the next picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3mFS.png)

And the next code:

```
public void SetMaxAndMinValueAxisY(List<double> residuals)
{
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = residuals.Max() + 0.00001;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = residuals.Min() - 0.00001;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 0;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = true;
}
```

I want the interval to be counted from zero, what should i do?

Comment: What do you mean with "set an interval"? What exactly should happen, can you please specify?

Comment: I want the same interval to be drawn up and down from y = 0.
I think, I can add point (x, 0) (any x) and it will be work, but it is bad idea.

Comment: Then save the interval in an array and loop through it. What do you think?

Comment: You can try to set the IntervalOffset, probably to a suitable y-value.